# PR или пиар?

Tags: аббревиатуры

Читал аннотацию к фильму на торренте и встретил написание "PR-кампания".
Понятно, что термин "пиар" - это аббревиатура словосочетания "public relation". Но как все-таки правильно писать на русском языке: английскими буквами PR или допустимо написание "пиар", тем более, что оно настолько вошло в язык, что о том, что это аббревиатура, никто уже не вспоминает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова плотно вошло в обиход и даже породило глаголы: пиариться, пропиарить, вполне понятные для основной массы населения. Чем занимается PR-компания, поймут единицы, а вот про пиар-компанию - единицы не поймут. Поэтому я использовал бы **пиар**.

Answer (score 2):

У нас в метро периодически вывешивают "ликбез" (с рекомендуемым написанием "трудных" слов) от Людмилы Вербицкой, ректора Университета. Подборка новых заимствований включала и "пиар".

Comment: Эх, у нас бы где-нибудь такое вывешивали...